# Is there a ready rails solution for a project like this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to make a following project:

User goes to Index page
Loggs in to his account
After he loggs in - he can see the list of items (records) he owns.
He can edit/preview/delete/create items
Each of his items has :title, :features, :price fields and multiple pictures attached to it so that when he's on editing form - he can add/remove pictures, change values etc.
Would be also nice if he can preview changes before submitting a form.

I started to build it in Rails, but then I ran into an Active Admin gem, which was doing a good job generating really complex pages easily. So I had an idea - maybe someone already released a polished project or a gem that does what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a gem for your requirement. However, I can suggest some things for you.

For list of items and the fields, do this:

> rails g scaffold User title:string features:text price:decimal image:string

For authentication, I suggest you to go through 'device' gem.

Previewing is a little advanced and it needs to be done through jQuery.

If you want to make a beautiful users items page, use the gem 'twitter-bootstrap'. Go through the video http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics

Comment: oh, twitter-bootstrap is awesome. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Spree may be this is what you are looking for 
https://github.com/spree/spree

There is also a rails cast for this, do check that out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easy job to create it from scratch. Use Active Admin like you mentioned and for gallery [paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip). It's very easy to implement it. And like Arun Kumar wrote use rails generator to make your model, controller and view of items. Look at [rails scaffolding](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding).